# walletconnect v2 cdn for javascipt project

Tags: wallets, web3-providers, walletconnect

do we have an cdn for walletconnect v2 for using in pure js project?
after that we need to get provider and getsinger for using data and creating contract ethers.js by signer for call functions

Comment: What is the issue? It isn't clear from the question.

Answer (score 0):

In my project, I used version 1, which is now obsolete, and I did not find any source for using version 2 that is for Java. If you have a source to solve this problem, please share it with me.